# can only make with only one object file in makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile, cross-compiling

So I am trying to make my own make file for cross compiling code. I am getting the C files out of a folder with a wildcard but when I have more than one C files in the csources folder it will not create the object files.

```
# Macros
linux_compiler = gcc
win32_compiler = i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
win64_compiler = x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
program = main

cfolder = csources
headerfolder = hsources
objectfolder = osources

csources = $(wildcard $(cfolder)/*.c)
hsources = $(wildcard $(headerfolder)/*.h)

osources_linux = $(patsubst $(cfolder)/%.c,$(objectfolder)/%_linux.o,$(wildcard $(cfolder)/*.c))
osources_win32 = $(patsubst $(cfolder)/%.c,$(objectfolder)/%_win32.o,$(wildcard $(cfolder)/*.c))
osources_win64 = $(patsubst $(cfolder)/%.c,$(objectfolder)/%_win64.o,$(wildcard $(cfolder)/*.c))

# First target
all: clearscreen $(program)_win64 $(program)_win32 $(program)_linux
    $(info $(program) created $(csources))

# Use to force compile the program
force: clean clearscreen $(program)_win64 $(program)_win32 $(program)_linux
    $(info $(program) forcible created)

$(program)_linux: $(osources_linux) $(objectfolder)/$(program)_linux.o
    $(linux_compiler) $(objectfolder)/$(program)_linux.o $(osources_linux) -o $(program)_linux

$(program)_win32: $(osources_win32) $(objectfolder)/$(program)_win32.o
    $(win32_compiler) $(objectfolder)/$(program)_win32.o $(osources_win32) -o $(program)_win32

$(program)_win64: $(osources_win64) $(objectfolder)/$(program)_win64.o
    $(win64_compiler) $(objectfolder)/$(program)_win64.o $(osources_win64) -o $(program)_win64

$(osources_linux): $(csources) $(hsources) 
    $(linux_compiler) -c $(csources) -o $(osources_linux) 

$(osources_win32): $(csources) $(hsources) 
    $(win32_compiler) -c $(csources) -o $(osources_win32) 

$(osources_win64): $(csources) $(hsources) 
    $(win64_compiler) -c $(csources) -o $(osources_win64)  

$(objectfolder)/$(program)_linux.o: $(program).c
    $(linux_compiler) -c $(program).c -o $(objectfolder)/$(program)_linux.o

$(objectfolder)/$(program)_win32.o: $(program).c
    $(win32_compiler) -c $(program).c -o $(objectfolder)/$(program)_win32.o

$(objectfolder)/$(program)_win64.o: $(program).c
    $(win64_compiler) -c $(program).c -o $(objectfolder)/$(program)_win64.o

clearscreen:
    clear

clean:
    rm $(objectfolder)/*.o
```

I don't know that much about makefiles, I thought this should work, but it's not making any object files.

```
$(osources_win64): $(csources) $(hsources)      
     $(win64_compiler) -c $(csources) -o $(osources_win64)
```

And the error I got when I do have more then one c file in the cfolder:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c csources/log.c csources/SDL_add.c -o osources/log_win64.o osources/SDL_add_win64.o  
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc: error: osources/SDL_add_win64.o: No such file or directory
makefile:132: recipe for target 'osources/SDL_add_win64.o' failed
make: *** [osources/SDL_add_win64.o] Error 1
```

Solution:

```
###############################################################################
## This is the makefile for the application within the SDL2 (game) engine    ##
## This will crosscompile your code to linux and windows (32 and 64 bit)     ##
## Started development in 19-02-2016                                         ##
## Version = 1.00                                                            ##
## Status  = Operational                                                     ##     
## Author  = Marijn van Tricht                                               ##
##                                                                           ##
## === Log ================================================================= ##
##                                                                           ##
## 20-02-2016 - Version 1.00 created                                         ##
##                                                                           ##
###############################################################################

###############################################################################
## Read below to understand the makefile                                     ##
###############################################################################
##                                                                           ##
## === Functions =========================================================== ##
##                                                                           ##
## generic format of a target                                                ##            
## Target: Dependencies                                                      ##
## <TAB> Command                                                             ##
##                                                                           ##
## Target:                                                                   ##
## Target is a function, when make is called it will automaticly select the  ##
## first target.                                                             ##
##                                                                           ##
## Dependencies:                                                             ##
## Here there's a list of files or function needed to execute the command.   ##
## When a depencie is a function it will execute that function before it     ##
## will make the target.                                                     ##
##                                                                           ##
## Command:                                                                  ##
## Here the information is provided which will be pasted in the terminal.    ##
##                                                                           ##
## === Compiling =========================================================== ##
##                                                                           ##
## One of those commands could be to compile your code. general thats what a ##
## makefile is made to do.                                                   ##
##                                                                           ##
## In the simplest form the command to compile a program is a compiler like  ## 
## gcc or g++ and a c or cpp file as an argument.                            ##
## For example:                                                              ##
## gcc main.c                                                                ##
##                                                                           ##
## this will generate a program called a.out                                 ##
##                                                                           ##
## === Parameters ========================================================== ##
##                                                                           ##
## With this command you can give a lot of parameters.                       ##
## For example -o main will change the output filename to main.out so,       ##
## gcc main.c -o main will result in a file called main.out                  ##
##                                                                           ##
## All the parameters used by this makefile are described and listed below.  ##
##                                                                           ##
##  -o <filename>   | This will change the output name of function to be     ## 
##                  | filename                                               ##
##                                                                           ##
##  -c              | This will compile to the program to objectfiles. This  ##
##                  | can than later be compiled again with the compiler to  ##
##                  | a program. The change is that the objectfiles won't be ##
##                  | deleted by the compiler.                               ##
##                                                                           ##
## === Macros ============================================================== ##
##                                                                           ##
## Macros can copy paste lines in your code for example you could make a     ##
## macro for the compiler you'll use. You can do that by adding the          ## 
## following:                                                                ##
## Compiler = gcc                                                            ##
##                                                                           ##
## This can then be pasted into the code by using $(compiler).               ##
## So Macros can be defined be the = sign and can be pasted by $(macro).     ##
##                                                                           ##
## === Specific functions ================================================== ##
##                                                                           ## 
## There are a few Specific functions you can use in a makefile those are    ##
## used in the sameway as macros do a list of specific functions that are    ##
## used in this makefile are listed below.                                   ##
##                                                                           ##
##  $(info <text>)                         | The <text> will be printed in   ## 
##                                         | the terminal                    ##
##                                                                           ##
##  $(wildcard <folder>/*.<format>         | This will select all the        ##
##                                         | .<format> files in the selected ##
##                                         | <folder>                        ##
##                                                                           ##
##  $(patsubst <replace>,<with>,<file(s)>) | With this we can replace the    ##
##                                         | name(s) of some file(s)         ##
##                                                                           ##
###############################################################################

# Macros
linux_compiler = gcc
win32_compiler = i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
win64_compiler = x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc

linux_flags = -lSDL2
win32_flags = -lSDL2main -lSDL2
win64_flags = -lSDL2main -lSDL2

program = main

cfolder = csources/
headerfolder = hsources/
objectfolder = osources/

csources = $(wildcard $(cfolder)*.c)
hsources = $(wildcard $(headerfolder)*.h)

osources_linux = $(patsubst $(cfolder)%.c,$(objectfolder)%_linux.o,$(wildcard $(cfolder)*.c))
osources_win32 = $(patsubst $(cfolder)%.c,$(objectfolder)%_win32.o,$(wildcard $(cfolder)*.c))
osources_win64 = $(patsubst $(cfolder)%.c,$(objectfolder)%_win64.o,$(wildcard $(cfolder)*.c))

# First target
all: clearscreen $(objectfolder) $(program)_win64 $(program)_win32 $(program)_linux
    $(info $(program) created)

# Use to force compile the program
force: clean clearscreen $(objectfolder) $(program)_win64 $(program)_win32 $(program)_linux
    $(info $(program) forcible created)

$(program)_linux: $(osources_linux) $(objectfolder)$(program)_linux.o
    $(linux_compiler) $(linux_flags) $(objectfolder)$(program)_linux.o $(osources_linux) -o $(program)_linux

$(program)_win32: $(osources_win32) $(objectfolder)$(program)_win32.o
    $(win32_compiler) $(objectfolder)$(program)_win32.o $(osources_win32) -o $(program)_win32 $(win32_flags)

$(program)_win64: $(osources_win64) $(objectfolder)$(program)_win64.o
    $(win64_compiler) $(objectfolder)$(program)_win64.o $(osources_win64) -o $(program)_win64 $(win64_flags)

$(objectfolder)%_linux.o: $(cfolder)%.c
    $(linux_compiler) -c $? -D LINUX -o $@

$(objectfolder)%_win32.o: $(cfolder)%.c
    $(win32_compiler) -c $? -D WIN32 -o $@

$(objectfolder)%_win64.o: $(cfolder)%.c
    $(win64_compiler) -c $? -D WIN64 -o $@

$(objectfolder)$(program)_linux.o: $(program).c
    $(linux_compiler) -c $(program).c -D LINUX -o $(objectfolder)$(program)_linux.o 

$(objectfolder)$(program)_win32.o: $(program).c
    $(win32_compiler) -c $(program).c -D WIN32 -o $(objectfolder)$(program)_win32.o

$(objectfolder)$(program)_win64.o: $(program).c
    $(win64_compiler) -c $(program).c -D WIN64 -o $(objectfolder)$(program)_win64.o

$(objectfolder):
    mkdir $(objectfolder)

clearscreen:
    clear

clean:
    rm $(objectfolder)*.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some generic rules to make object files in each platform.

```
$(objectfolder)/%_linux.o: $(cfolder)/%.c
    $(linux_compiler) -c $? -o $@

$(objectfolder)/%_win32.o: $(cfolder)/%.c
    $(win32_compiler) -c $? -o $@

$(objectfolder)/%_win64.o: $(cfolder)/%.c
    $(win64_compiler) -c $? -o $@
```

Comment: You'll need to define the dependencies for the executables to include all the .o files.

Comment: like? $(program)_linux: $(objectfolder)%_linux.o

Comment: @MVT, you have already defined the object files as dependencies. Unless I am missing something, you should be good to go.

Comment: If I just copy paste that then I get 'make: *** No rule to make target 'osources/%_win64.o', needed by 'main_win64'.  Stop.'

Comment: @MVT, My bad. `%.c` should be `$(cfolder)/%.c`.

Comment: still the same problem I am sorry that I can't give anymore specific information I don't get what this does.

Comment: @MVT, This might be helpful: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Rules.html#Pattern-Rules.

Comment: @R Sahu yes thanks it works now it was actually was my own fault why the last function wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example:

```
sakkath ~ $ gcc -c file1.c file2.c -o file1.o file2.o
gcc: error: file2.o: No such file or directory
sakkath ~ $
```

You cannot specify two arguments to -o, and if you try to use the "-o" flag twice, this happens:

```
gcc: fatal error: cannot specify -o with -c, -S or -E with multiple files
compilation terminated.
```

The only reason you can specify multiple files when you are NOT using -c, is because the linking stage is invoked, and by definition one executable is produced by linking multiple files together.  But this is still only one argument to "-o".  The reason you are getting the error you are, is because gcc is interpreting the file you are trying to specify as the second argument to "-o" as an additional input file.  Consider this:

```
gcc file1.c -o main file2.c
```

This will not create two output files, but will be exactly the same as if you invoked it this way (the order of arguments doesn't really matter basically):

```
gcc file1.c file2.c -o main
```

Comment: -S produces assembler output, -E just invokes the preprocessor (similar to how -c only invokes the compilation stage and stops before linking).    

This error message is saying that you cannot specify multiple files with -o (can't use "-o" more than once) with -c, OR with -S, OR with -E, i.e., it doesn't work with any of those arguments. You removed your comment! It makes my comment look silly by itself :P. What you need to do is invoke `gcc -c` for *each* .c file.
Please upvote my answer by the way, I am trying hard to earn reputation because I want 50 so I can comment on other answers :).

Comment: oh yeah sorry but how do you invoke on each file?

Comment: Exactly what @RSahu said in his answer :).  You make a rule that says "for each .o file target, invoke gcc". Then you make your executable depend on each of these .o targets. You have something similar like this going on, but I'm not sure what `program.o` is (as I said, you can't combine multiple source files into one object file). Somewhere to start might be changing the line `$(program)_linux: $(osources_linux) $(objectfolder)/$(program)_linux.o` to `$(program)_linux: $(osources_linux)`, forgive me if I'm incorrect, but this seems to make sense to me...

Comment: ... (continued) Work on replacing your ".o" recipes with the ones @RSahu suggested. Also, note that it's not necessary to have the .o files--you can just have an executable rule that directly combines/compiles all .c files. The one benefit of having the .o files is that it makes recompiling after changes quicker (only those object files that corresponding source files have changed need to be recreated), but it might be a nice starting point to have a simpler Makefile that skips the object file creation (for now). Also, thanks much for the upvote :).

Comment: Your comment to the other answer "like? $(program)_linux: $(objectfolder)%_linux.o" (I can't comment on his answer until 50 rep. :P), it would be more like `$(program)_linux: $(osources_linux)`, kind of like what you have except I don't know what the additional `$(objectfolder)/$(program)_linux.o` is (read my previous comment).

Comment: I don't really quite understand yet, but $(program)_linux is for selecting a target for the linking and I wanted to split main from the other sources and I create 3 object files with _win64, _win32 and _linux

Comment: Yeah, you can't combine multiple source files into a single object file.  There's just no way to do it. The only way to combine files is by linking, and by definition creating an object file skips (stops prior to) the linking stage. You could instead make a rule called $(program)_linux, and have your executable depend on this rule, and this rule will compile all the source files you want, but it can be a phony rule (i.e., it won't actually compile anything with the same name (kind of like how 'clean' and 'all' are "phony" rules).

Comment: A comment that is also directed towards the other answer's comments: you might want to try not using variables and expansions and stuff and first hardcode every file name--at least until you can get it working. Then you can slowly start adding in the variables, etc. (so you can find exactly what is and what isn't working and exactly where things are going wrong).

Comment: Your error about the "No rule to make target 'osources/%_win64.o'", that's because your line looks like `$(program)_win64: $(osources_win64) $(objectfolder)/$(program)_win64.o`. Like I said, you can't have a program.o file that combines multiple source files. Remove that part of  your rule, make it simply `$(program)_win64: $(osources_win64)` and try this.

Comment: Thanks again for the upvote. Let me know how you make out and if you need any more help. Now, if I can only write an answer that becomes an accepted answer...

Comment: yeah I am sorry you explained it very well, I understand it now after a night sleep. but the post doesn't really contain the direct answer for if any user quickly browses with the same problem.

Comment: It's okay, I'm not saying my answer should have been the accepted one. I just wanted to provide you with that info regardless :) (obviously I was getting to the correct answer via the comments though). I am just saying I'm excited for *any* answer of mine to become an accepted answer :). Good news though, I went from ~25 rep. since we last spoke to 41, I'm almost there :). Glad you understand everything and got it all working, happy to help :). (BTW I think both of our answers are good because each address different parts of your question so I'm happy mine is here regardless).

Comment: Good luck! almost there :)

Comment: now I am just curious but how do you search for questions? I think I can help with other simple C, vhdl questions, but I never know how to find those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104017/discussion-between-rastajedi-and-mvt).